# Restart apache2 on Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache2, apache2.4, apache2-module, ispconfig

I have ISPConfig3 configured on my dedicated server with a created website on it.

When I try to restart my apache2 service with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `service apache2 restart` my website display a 403 error with `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

I always access to my website with https (certificate created and generated with ISPConfig).

Sometimes, I restart entirely the server to get again my previous accesses, but it does not work all the time.

I know that I configured access to my IP server to this this page. As my IP serveur is pointing to /var/www, no index.php are in there, so a 403 error is resulting (-Indexes is set in configuration).

Actually, it is as if ISPConfig vhost doesn't work, and my website is redirected to /var/www.

I suspect a port issue, because my ISPConfig is always available and https works.

Do you have any ideas where the problem could be ?

Thanks.

Comment: if you can have access to the command line, can you give us the content of the corresponding file in the directory /etc/apache2/sites-available/ ?

Comment: @Nico Of course, here is 000-default.conf : http://pastebin.com/QqQRvGvm and the one generated by ISPConfig : http://pastebin.com/KpeUYnUe

Comment: and what is the same file for your created website ? (you can hide the domain name as you've done for the serverAdmin email)

Comment: @Nico This is precisely the second link I shared, it's the one generated by ISPConfig.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see, maybe there is no problem in these files... Did you verify the permissions on your web directory and on its content ? the read permission is the minimal requirement... but I think it's not the problem, but you can have a look

Comment: @Nico Yes I did, I even compare with the permissions of a colleague on his server and we have substantially the same thing ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have -Indexes it means "Do not allow indexing"

the "-" is "Remove this option", remove the - and you would get a directory listing.

Comment: I already know that, and it's normal, I don't want anyone get access to `/var/www` like my ip address does. With ISPConfig my domain should point to `/var/www/<mydomain>/web` and not to `/var/www`